# Thai Visa: Will a Re-entry Help Me?

Tags: visa, thailand

Currently on an ED Thai visa, which needs to be renew again in two weeks .
Problem: I have to leave Thailand for 3 weeks in two days so I won't be able to extend my visa while in Thailand.

I thought of getting a re-entry but:
1. I'm not sure if I'll get it, based on the fact that I need to extend it while outside.
2. Even if I will get it, not sure if it's going to help.

Probably not, but is it possible to extend in a Thai consulate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid, the answer is no.

Re-entry permit is only available **for a period of your valid stay** in the country. The date is specified in your most recent stamp.

Yes, you are eligible for preliminary extension of your stay if you have a good reason. **Traveling abroad is a good reason** (just show your air ticket), but in general, this can also be a long travel within the country.

However, in order to get an extension, you need to get papers from your school, proving that you are still attending the classes — just likewise you do every time when you extend your stay.

**Caveat.** With current Thai regulations, there are two ways to extend your stay:

1. "Normal" extension, in two steps: (1) You pay 1900 THB, **get 15 days**, during which the Immigration officers may come to your school and check if you really attend the classes. (2) Then, you come to the Immigration office and **get another 75 days**;
2. "Special" extension: 90 days at once, 3900 THB.

Obviously, you need the 2nd way since you won't be there.

**Suggested steps:**

1. Run to your school and kindly ask them for the necessary paperwork; I can't guarantee they will be able to do it within two days, but give it a try;
2. Go to the Immigration office and:

   1. Extend your stay; if asked for the reason (of preliminary extension), show up your air tickets and say you also plan to ask for the re-entry permit;
   2. Get a re-entry permit;